# Log files are not created on magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and  recently install Magento 1.9.1.0 on Amazon EC2 to play with it, I have few issues with it and want to debug few pages. but for some reasons the log files are not created in 
InstallDIR >> var >> log , I have enabled logs in developer section under System >> configuration.

I have also checked it in /tmp/magento/var and /var/log folder but it does not exist there either.

in my index.php I have uncommented below lines

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
 ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
```

compilation is also disabled under System >> tools
Cache is disabled under System >> Cache Management

I don't know what's wrong, can anybody please help me out.

Comment: Do you have write permission on the var/log folder?

Comment: log folder wasn't there by default, I created it manually and gave 777 permissions still it is not creating.

Comment: just check the store name and website configuration under developer section

Comment: I have a same kind of problem, do you get solution for that